# Which keyboard key is the HELP key on IBM i green screen

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a screen program which says **"HELP - INSTRUCTIONS"**
[image]

I know CMD 1 - F1 Key, CMD 8 - F8 Key and so on, but even after trying all combinations from F1 to F24 keys, I am not able to get HELP key.

Behind the scenes, I see indicator 90 (IN90) is checked, if it is ON then a HELPER program is called.

But I seem to have failed to equate IN90 on physical keyboard.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Indicator 90 is irrelevant in terms of having someone help you, because that is specific to your display file and RPG program. In general, any command key can be associated with any indicator. What you do need to know is what keyboard key is mapped to HELP, and that is *also* configurable, but configurable on the user's end (in your case, the user may be yourself). Each user could potentially have a different key mapped to HELP, though it's rare to change it from its default of Alt+F1, as mentioned by @jiarong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default HELP Key Functions for a 5250 Layout is [Alt+F1](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/personal-communications/5.9?topic=reference-key-functions-keyboard-setup).